# Calling stored procedure from hbm

Tags: hibernate, hql

i am stuck at calling up a procedure which is stored in oracle and returns selected columns from the Hibernate client.

employee3.hbm.xml

```
        <hibernate-mapping>
          <class name="Employee" table="employee3">
            <id name="eid" column="eid"/>
      <property name="fname" column="first_name"/>
      <property name="lname" column="last_name"/>
      <property name="email" column="email"/>
   </class>


<sql-query name="test1" callable="true">
  <return  alias ="test1" class ="Employee">
    <return-property name="fname" column="first_name"/>
    <return-property name="lname" column="last_name"/>
</return>
  {?=call get_empdetails_assg(?,?)}
</sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

testClient.java

```
Session ses =sf.openSession();

Transaction tx = ses.beginTransaction();
System.out.println("--------------got tx object-----------");
Employee eb =null;

SQLQuery q1=(SQLQuery)ses.createSQLQuery("test1");


System.out.println("--------------q1 processing-----------");
q1.setString(0,"v%");
```

Stored procedure:

```
create or replace  procedure get_empdetails_assg(mycursor out sys_refcursor,cond in           varchar)

as 
begin
open mycursor for

select eb.first_name,eb.last_name from employee3 eb where eb.first_name like cond;

end;
```

i am getting the output error while tryingt to set the cond in sql with setString(0,"v%")

```
--------------q1 processing-----------                                          Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No positional parameters in query: test1                                                                 at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:442)
```

Please any inputs ..am tired of trying:(

Regards
Jay

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the parameters properly and you need to call `getNamedQuery()`, not `createSQLQuery()`.

Try this.

```
Query query = session.getNamedQuery("test1");
query.setParameter(1, "some_vlaue");
query.setParameter(2, "some_vlaue");
List result = query.list();
```

Comment: i changed to getNamedQuery("test1"); but how shall i retrieve the elements . its works fine with iterating all the list elements when i call a statement like "select * from" but how to retrieve column data that is present as out in called procedure.

Comment: With the above code `query.list();` returns list of objects which is of type Employee as you specified in the xml `class="Employee"`. So iterate through the list cast the object to Employee, that's it.

Comment: while i use q1.list() following exception is being thrown-q1 processing------Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method) at java.util.ArrayList.toArray(ArrayList.java:390 at org.hibernate.internal.util.collections.ArrayHelper.toTypeArray(ArrayHelper.java:106) at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.typeArray(AbstractQueryImpl.java:986) at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.getQueryParameters(AbstractQueryImpl.java:994)at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.getQueryParameters(SQLQueryImpl.java:184)at org.hibernate.internal.SQL

Comment: Edit your question and provide full statck trace, Read [this article](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-call-store-procedure-in-hibernate/). It shows many ways to use stored procedure.